# Program not from Oracle that can read Oracle export dumps?

Tags: database, oracle-database

I am maintaining an Oracle database. Recently, my boss asked me what would happend if we for some reason suddenly could no longer use Oracle products. So I am now looking for some kind of software that is not developed by Oracle but could still be used to "save" our data.

My requierments:

1. Is not an Oracle product.
2. Can read Oracle files created by Oracles [export utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm).
3. Can convert the data it reads into some other commonly used non Oracle format (such as SQL or XML).
4. Windows software is prefered, but anything goes.
5. Open source would be nice.
6. Price is not a big issue, but obviously cheaper is better all else equal.